# Enabling server certificate authentication in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, ssl-certificate

As the title says, i'd like to enable the authentication of server certificates in jmeter. Is it possible to configure it?

What i found so far is [this article](https://flood.io/blog/mutual-two-way-ssl-with-jmeter/)
According to this, "HTTP Client 4 implementation will use a TrustAll scheme". Mainly i use this client implementation (in jmeter version 3.0 or 3.1) since this is the more advanced/versatile in jmeter. But this way jmeter won't catch cases where server certificates are invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl):

> The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc. This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers.

There is no easy way of disabling this behavior without modification of JMeter source code, however you can use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) in order to check the server certificate and/or [certificate chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust).

The relevant code would be something like:

```
def factory = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

def socket = factory.createSocket('example.com', 443);

socket.withStreams { input, output ->
    output.withWriter {
        it << 'hello'
        it.flush()
    }
}
```

Replace `example.com` and `443` with your server host and port. If there is no problem with certificate(s) - the request will be successful, otherwise you will see error with details in the sample result.

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about the concept of custom scripting in JMeter

Comment: You are a treasure sir! :) Thanks for the prompt reply! I've got the following result: `Response code: 500
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` I know that the cert is messed up on the target, so probably i used your advice properly.