# Enabling detailed server certificate authentication in jmeter

Tags: ssl, jmeter

I am asking for a bit more detailed answer than what Dmitri T posted here:
[Enabling server certificate authentication in jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408197/enabling-server-certificate-authentication-in-jmeter)

I need to alert on bad server certificates and the code here posted (and pasted below) works great, however I want to provide more details.  Due to some unfortunate change control process issues (being addressed) someone installed a revoked certificate on a server.  That obviously took down the site and it took way to long to identify the issue.  Since I work in monitoring I wanted have my synthetic transaction scripts verify the certificate.  But not only do I want to alert on bad ones I want to provide as much detail as possible to identify the problem.  Over at badssl.com they have quite a number of invalid certificate examples.

So my question is how can I expand on Dmitri's code to provide that the certificate is bad, but also that it's expired/revoked/etc.?  Everything I have tried so far just gives me `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

```
def factory = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

def socket = factory.createSocket('example.com', 443);

socket.withStreams { input, output ->
    output.withWriter {
        it << 'hello'
        it.flush()
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

You can get really verbose information regarding establishing the HTTPS connectivity by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up

References:

- [How to Analyze Java SSL Errors](https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-ssl-errors)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)
- [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)

Comment: That will work only for my desktop trials.  Unfortunately I don't have access to the monitoring stations to add that line to the system.properties file.

Comment: And just to be thorough I did put that into my jmeter script.properties file, but I still can only get the following information:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target