# How to enable certificate verification with jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Everywhere I look I see that jmeter turns off certificate verification by default.
Its [documentatoin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl) says "The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc. This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers."

Is this a configuration option, or there is no way to configure it?
I would like to have jmeter to verify the certificate, as part of the test. I have tried example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53409702/9149561), however it didn't fit our needs

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "switch" to enable/disable the SSL verification in JMeter, you will have to patch [LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.checkAndInit() function](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/hc/LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.java#L62) in order to enable certificate checking functionality.

Once done you will need to [build JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/building.html)

As a workaround you can utilize [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) and define your requests via [Java Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) or [JUnit Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter/) or [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid this was the case. I thought of a solution without the need of maintaining a unique unofficial version. At the moment I am using socat to act as a proxy, and it works, but I am looking of a solution without the need of a third party process.
I would seriously consider the Java request option. Thanks!

Comment: Eventually we created a JSR223 sampler that uses setSSLSocketFactory() to the HttpsURLConnection